# Connection refused to Redis in Docker while creating a cluster

Tags: docker, redis

I'm trying to create a Redis cluster with 6 nodes using Docker. I've created a folder named redis inside that I have 6 nodes folders namely node1, node2,...,node6. In these folders, node1.conf, node2.conf,...,node6.conf files are placed with the following code.

```
port 8001
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 15000
bind 127.0.0.1
```

port addresses for other nodes are 8002, 8003,..., 8006. A network named redis-network is created.

I set up containers for the nodes using the below command.

```
docker run -v D:/Redis/node1/node1.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis -p 8001:8001 --name redis_node1 --network redis-network redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/
```

For each container, I've changed the port number, container name, and folder name accordingly.

Then, I run the following command inside the shell of one of the containers

```
redis-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:8001 127.0.0.1:8002 127.0.0.1:8003 127.0.0.1:8004 127.0.0.1:8005 127.0.0.1:8006 --cluster-replicas 1
```

Then, I get the following error:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:8001: Connection refused
```

What is causing this error? How to resolve it?

Comment: Could you try to `bind 0.0.0.0` instead of `bind 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: No, I will try it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. It's still not working.